# Does any scripture provide any inner meaning of worshipping Devi Durga to appease Rahu?

Tags: scripture, durga, rahu, inner-meaning

In Hindu astrology Rahu represents ***materialism, mischief, fear, insatisfaction, obsession and confusion/illusion***. Rahu is also associated with politicians and occult sciences.

There are [many questions](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/search?q=rahu) that had already been posted on Rahu-Ketu in this site.  My area of Interest is different.

It was stated in many astrological books that Devi Durga should be worshipped to appease Rahu.

My question is - Does any scripture provide any inner meaning of worshipping Devi Durga to appease Rahu?

**Edit**

***Inner meaning*** means that which is esoteric/hidden meaning. For understanding the outer meaning, knowledge of language is sufficient. However, to understand the Inner meaning, deeper understanding of the subject is required.

For example: the Outer meaning of the word brahmachari is celebate, whereas the inner meaning is **ONE** who remained merged in BRAHMAN and **moves in BRAHMAN**

Comment: Can u pls elaborate what do u mean by "inner meaning"...

Comment: *Inner meaning* means that which is esoteric/hidden meaning.  For understanding the outer meaning, knowledge of language is sufficient.  However, to understand the *Inner meaning*, deeper understanding of the subject is required @YDS. For example: the Outer meaning of the word **brahmachari** is celebate, whereas the inner meaning is ONE who remained merged in BRAHMAN and moves in BRAHMAN

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it is mentioned in any scripture. But from the meanings of the words you can make out why Goddess Durga needs to be worshipped to appease Rahu.

Some of the meanings of the word 'Durga' in Sanskrit - inaccessible, not easy to reach. So Goddess Durga is essentially the Source of the existence Herself.

Some of the meanings of the word 'Rahu' - let alone, let be.

So the entity that got separated from the Source of existence which is the ultimate truth being alone (with only material body as its identity) is constantly in search of its Source i.e. Goddess Durga. In the process Rahu does everything and all kinds of mischiefs in hoping to get back to the Source.

And without a Guru Rahu can never reach Goddess Durga. That is why Rahu only listens to Jupiter in a natal chart like his Guru.

Comment: I am asking for inner meaning, which indicates that it is not directly available in ONE scripture, but to be correlated with other issues available in another scripture also.  Further research is required.

Comment: I thought it was very clear from my answer. The esoteric meaning of Rahu in search of Goddess Durga is that the jiva identified with only body is always in search of something that is inaccessible to the jiva, the real identity the which is the Source of existence, Goddess Durga without the grace of a Guru. I bet no one can go more deeper than this.

Comment: Well let's see if anyone comes up with a better approach then I will take back what I said.

Answer (score 0):

Brihat parashara hora shastra mentions worship of durga as a remedy for Rahu in chapters dealing with antardashas.

Comment: I am looking for an inner meaning of this issue, please

Answer (score 0):

Rahu is basically ruler of [Ardra nakshatra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ardra_(nakshatra)) in Gemini, and represents the farthest point from the [Mula nakshatra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mula_(nakshatra)), of house Sagittarius in which the [Galactic centre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galactic_Center), or Brahmsthan resides when seen from earth. This means Ardra is also farthest point from the Milky way's Galactic centre and hence the constellation where Rahu, the darkness, can exalt.

[image]

[image]

Now, Ardra which mean tears(of face) is ruled by Rudra, while Mula which means the root or tail is ruled by Niriti, the goddess of desolution and destruction. Rudra and Niriti are the original names of Shiva-Shakti used in Vedic astrology and Vastu Shastra and represents the head and feet which also signify Rahu, the head(ego) and Ketu, the tail(moksha). Hence, Rahu exalts in Ardra, Gemini and Ketu in Mula, Sagittarius. Animal sign for both the constellations is a pair of dogs, which represents the outcast planet Ketu and ride of Bhairava/Bhairavi.

[image]
[image]

The same 27 constellations and 9 planets rule any piece of land on earth via Vastu Shastra in the form of Vastu Purusha, and the Ishan kona(North-East corner) ruled by Shiva/Jupiter or head(place for temple) while the Nairutya kone(South-West corner) ruled by [Nirrti](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nir%E1%B9%9Bti)/Rahu and between them is the centre of Brahmsthan.

Since, **Nirrti is the original name of Goddess Durga, who controls Rahu(the darkness) or South-West(Nairutya) corner in an earthly house or horoscope(as Rahu debilities in Sagittarius or Mula nakshatra), hence to pacify Rahu, astrologers talk about worshipping Durga.**

Note: **The world is facing current COVID-19 pandemic because [Rahu was in Gemini](https://barbarapijan.com/bpa/Gochara_RahuKetu/RahuKetuSamchara_TransitsTable.htm), from March 2019 till September 2020(18 months) and in Arda**, the constellation of tears and destruction in the beginning of 2020 as Rahu moves in retrograde or reverse direction. Earlier, Rahu was in Gemini transit, 18 years back, i.e. in around 2000-2001 and brought calamities and several changes after World Trade attack on 9-11-2001 and Gujarat Earthquakes in 2000. Rahu also represents ego, research and changes, hence scientists are involved in finding vaccines for COVID-19 virus in 2020.

Comment: As far as I know Rahu's exalted position is in Vrishabha rasi, and thus it debilitates in Vrischika rasi. Am I wrong?

Comment: @SrimannarayanaKV Rahu is a shadow planet with no visible house, hence several casual astrologers without deep understanding, are confused about its actual nature. Rahu is lord of 3 constellations i.e. Ardra, Swati and Shatabishta and hence exalts in its houses i.e. Gemini, Libra and Aquarius. Basically if Rahu is any one of its house, it automatically aspects all the three houses as it has aspects of 1,5,9 similar to Jupiter and Ketu. Similarly, Ketu exalts in its opposite houses i.e. Sagittarius, Aries and Leo. Rahu is mini Saturn, while Ketu is mini Mars.

Comment: Yes! I agree that 2 different schools think differently.  Let us leave aside this issue and come to question part.  I think, your statement - **Nirrti is the original name of Goddess Durga, who controls Rahu(the darkness)** needs elaboration, as I am asking for inner meaning. @ManuKumar

Comment: Hence, Rahu exalts and has good effects in the one of the allies of Saturn that are Mercury, Venus which are houses of Gemini, Virgo and Aquarius, while Ketu with one of the allies of Mars that are Sun and Jupiter in Aries, Leo and Sagittarius. Rahu goes with Asura planets while its opposite Ketu with Sura planets, hence Rahu is enemy of sun and moon.

Comment: On a side Note, I have Rahu in Ardra - 4 pada and in 10th House :-), but I faced lot of difficulties during 2019-20, when Rahu was in Mithuna Rasi.  What do you say? @ManuKumar

Comment: @SrimannarayanaKV i explained in note, that everyone in world is facing problem because of Rahu in Ardra during 2019-20, as transit is same for everyone. Rahu is mainly linked with research and shadows and occult sciences, Einstein was born with Ardra as Lagna and he did new researches. You can introspect, you must have become deeply interested in spirituality during 2019-20, but the true effect comes during Rahu Mahadasha in a person's life which is of 18 years. Rahu is an outcast and bring miseries but gives power to question authority, upheaval and reformation.

Comment: May be.  :-) Let us forget about personal issues.  Can you elaborate your statement - Nirrti is the original name of Goddess Durga, who controls Rahu(the darkness) 
 @ManuKumar

Comment: @SrimannarayanaKV Nirrti/Nairutya is the name of direction South-West(where Sun sets i.e. darkness) & personified as old Goddess sitting on crow.Now,South-West is place of Pitras(ancestors) while its opposite is North-east, place of Gods in the domain of space.These two directions are also called Uttarayan(Gods awake) and Dakshinayan(gods sleeping) of 6 months each in the yearly time domain or Sun & Moon or Ketu and Rahu Now, south-west and crows are associated with Pitras & ego, mother earth & ghosts which are part of Rahu i.e. shadows,coldness & hence controlled by Goddess kali/Durga/Nirrti.

Comment: You are still sticking to astrological explanations.  I want inner meaning please. @ManuKumar

Comment: @SrimannarayanaKV This is the inner meaning of Rahu and Ketu, you need to introspect and meditate to improve your mindfulness and spiritual comprehension. All these theories, directions, planets and this world are metaphors as they are not eternal and part of Maya itself and their meaning should be brainstormed in your ownself. Vastu and Astrology are universal mathematical implementation of Brahman in Space-Time continuum.